# sparklyr exception while reading csv file by infering schema : double

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am trying to read csv into Spark using `spark_read_csv` function. I am getting an exception while inferring the schema i.e I get exception when I set `infer_schema=TRUE`.

```
spark_read_csv(sc,"myDf",DatasetUrl)
```

I am getting the below exception:

> Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 90.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 90.0 (TID 151, localhost): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "cr1_fd_dttm"
>       at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:385)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVTypeCast$$anonfun$castTo$4.apply$mcD$sp(CSVInferSchema.scala:259)

However, when I try by setting `infer_schema=FALSE`, as expected everything is read as `chr` type.

This is how data looks like in the `cr1_fd_dttm` column:

```
      cr1_fd_dttm
            <chr>
1             0.0
2   1.45679112E12
3   1.45679166E12
4   1.45679154E12
5   1.45679274E12
6             0.0
7             0.0
8             0.0
9             0.0
10  1.45679118E12
```

Can someone help me in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just read the file without bringing it immediately into memory, coerce the fields numeric, and then load those results into memory. So the keys are to set `memory` to FALSE, `infer_schema` to FALSE, pass a list of the columns, coerce and then use `compute()` to save the results into Spark memory.  Here's a long winded, but working example:

```
mapped_flights <- spark_read_csv(sc, "mapped_flights", 
                      path =  "s3a://flights-data/full", 
                      memory = FALSE, 
                      infer_schema = FALSE,
                      columns = list(
                        Year = "character",
                        Month = "character",
                        DayofMonth = "character",
                        DayOfWeek = "character",
                        DepTime = "character",
                        CRSDepTime = "character",
                        ArrTime = "character",
                        CRSArrTime = "character",
                        UniqueCarrier = "character",
                        FlightNum = "character",
                        TailNum = "character",
                        ActualElapsedTime = "character",
                        CRSElapsedTime = "character",
                        AirTime = "character",
                        ArrDelay = "character",
                        DepDelay = "character",
                        Origin = "character",
                        Dest = "character",
                        Distance = "character",
                        TaxiIn = "character",
                        TaxiOut = "character",
                        Cancelled = "character",
                        CancellationCode = "character",
                        Diverted = "character",
                        CarrierDelay = "character",
                        WeatherDelay = "character",
                        NASDelay = "character",
                        SecurityDelay = "character",
                        LateAircraftDelay = "character")
                      )


flights <- mapped_flights %>%   mutate(
Year = as.integer(Year),
Month = as.integer(Month),
DayofMonth = as.integer(DayofMonth),
DayOfWeek = as.integer(DayOfWeek),
DepTime = as.integer(DepTime),
CRSDepTime = as.integer(CRSDepTime),
CRSArrTime = as.integer(CRSArrTime),
ArrTime = as.integer(ArrTime),
ActualElapsedTime = as.integer(ActualElapsedTime),
CRSElapsedTime = as.integer(CRSElapsedTime),
AirTime = as.integer(AirTime),
ArrDelay = as.double(ArrDelay),
DepDelay = as.double(DepDelay),
Distance = as.integer(Distance),
TaxiIn = as.integer(TaxiIn),
TaxiOut = as.integer(TaxiOut),
Cancelled = as.integer(Cancelled),
Diverted = as.integer(Diverted),
CarrierDelay = as.integer(CarrierDelay),
WeatherDelay = as.integer(WeatherDelay),
NASDelay = as.integer(NASDelay),
SecurityDelay = as.integer(SecurityDelay),
LateAircraftDelay = as.integer(LateAircraftDelay)) %>%   compute("flights")
```